# inaccurate distance measurements in Python

Tags: python, distance, geodjango, geos, geopy

I've tried several ways of measuring the distance between two points in my Django application and comparing the results to a reliable measurement. My numbers are *way* off. For example, I'm assuming the real distance between Dublin and Liverpool is ~217 km as reported by Google Maps:

[image]

Using `geopy` (should be [extremely accurate](https://github.com/geopy/geopy#measuring-distance)):

```
>>> from geopy.distance import distance
>>> dublin = (-6.270447, 53.339791)
>>> liverpool = (-2.991028, 53.402061)
>>> distance(dublin, liverpool).km
362.70989455939394
```

Using Django's GEOS API (less accurate linear calculation):

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
>>> dublin = Point(-6.270447, 53.339791, srid=3857)
>>> liverpool = Point(-2.991028, 53.402061, srid=3857)
>>> dublin.distance(liverpool)*100
328.00101418228877
```

**EDIT:**
Using a better projection for this area (UTM 30N) yields almost the same result:

```
>>> dublin.transform(32630)
>>> liverpool.transform(32630)
>>> dublin.distance(liverpool)*100
328.32200116442266
```

**In both cases I'm off by over 100km!** Measuring small distances (<1km) is just as inaccurate. What am I doing wrong here!?

Comment: For your django example, [doesn't EPSG:3857 use meters instead of degrees](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&reportDetail=short&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=EPSG:3857)?

Comment: Mercator should not ever be used for distance measurement, especially that far north.

Comment: I tried transforming the points to 32630 (UTM zone 30N) and got 328.3 km. Almost no difference in this case. There's nothing about projection in the `geopy` docs or in other answers, and the Vincenty distance I get should be accurate on the mm level.

Comment: `dublin.distance(liverpool)*100` <-- The fact that you had to multiply by 100 instead of 1000 should tell you something suspicious is going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you inverse the coordinates, it does not work (geopy uses (latitude,longitude) in the WGS84 crs)

```
 dublin = (53.33306,-6.24889)
 liverpool  = ( 53.41058,-2.97794)
 print distance(dublin, liverpool).km
 217.863019038
 print(vincenty(dublin, liverpool).kilometers)
 217.863019038
 print(great_circle(dublin, liverpool).kilometers)
 217.211596704
```

GEOS ([shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html), django) uses a Cartesian plane and the Euclidean distance. With [pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) (django uses (longitude,latitude))

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
dublin = Point(-6.270447, 53.339791, srid=4326) # in degrees
liverpool = Point(-2.991028, 53.402061, srid=4326) # in degrees
dublin.distance(liverpool)*100
328.00101418228877 # units ?
import pyproj
# conversion from WGS84 to epsg:3857
p1 = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')
a = pyproj.transform(p1,p2,-6.270447, 53.339791)
b = pyproj.transform(p1,p2,-2.991028, 53.402061)
dublin = Point(a) # in meters
liverpool = Point(b) # in meters
dublin.distance(liverpool)/1000 # Euclidean
365.2480859440489 #in km
```

But, as Vince says, the Mercator projection should not ever be used for distance measurement.

With the  EPSG:32630 (UTM zone 30N):

```
p3 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32630')
a = pyproj.transform(p1,p3,-6.270447, 53.339791)
b = pyproj.transform(p1,p3,-2.991028, 53.402061)
dublin = Point(a)
liverpool = Point(b)
dublin.distance(liverpool)/1000
218.32514783088294 #in km
```

And all the results (geopy and django ) are comparable with the Google distance or the [Distance from Liverpool to Dublin](http://www.distancefromto.net/distance-from-liverpool-gb-to-dublin-ie) (218 km)

Comment: The lon,lat / lat,lon confusion strikes again! I was sure I had it right there.