# How to extract CRS ellipsiod info in correct format for pyproj inverse

Tags: coordinate-system, python-3, pyproj, ellipsoid

I am using [pyproj inverse transform](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html) to add azimuth and distance "info" to an ordered geodataframe (`gdf`), but my datasets are in different locations around the world. I need to use a local UTM EPSG to get accurate azimuths and distances (e.g., discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198574/inaccurate-distance-measurements-in-python); this is common knowledge).

For a given EPSG, how can I systematically extract the `g = pyproj.Geod(ellps='X')` info from the CRS in the right format for `X`?

Below is my best attempt using `myellipsoid = CRS.from_user_input(myepsg).ellipsoid`, but it's in the wrong format. In this example, "GRS 1980" needs to be "GRS80"

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import pyproj
from pyproj import CRS

myid = [1, 1, 1]
myorder = [1, 2, 3]
lat = [5174925.07851924, 5174890.26832387, 5174855.45812849]
long = [1521631.6994673, 1521667.11033893, 1521702.52121056]
myepsg = 2193

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(myid, myorder, lat, long)), columns =['myid', 'myorder', 'lat', 'long']) 
gdf_pt = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['long'], df['lat']))
gdf_pt = gdf_pt.set_crs(epsg=myepsg)
myellipsoid = CRS.from_user_input(myepsg).ellipsoid

print(myellipsoid)
print(gdf_pt.crs)
display(gdf_pt)

ax = gdf_pt.plot();
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);


g = pyproj.Geod(ellps=myellipsoid) 
for i, r in gdf_pt.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    myinfo = g.inv(gdf_pt.long[i], gdf_pt.lat[i], gdf_pt.long[i-1], gdf_pt.lat[i-1])
    gdf_pt.loc[i, 'az_fwd'] = myinfo[0]
    gdf_pt.loc[i, 'az_back'] = myinfo[1]
    gdf_pt.loc[i, 'dist'] = myinfo[2]
    gdf_pt.loc[i, 'bearing'] = max(myinfo[1], myinfo[0])

display(gdf_pt)
```

[image]

Using: Windows 10; conda 4.8.2; Python 3.8.3; shapely 1.7.0 py38hbf43935_3 conda-forge; pyproj 2.6.1.post1 py38h1dd9442_0 conda-forge

Comment: Side note: geopandas 7+ uses the pyproj CRS object: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CRS.get_geod](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS.get_geod):

Here is an example:

```py
from pyproj import CRS

crs = CRS.from_epsg(epsg_code)
geod = crs.get_geod()
```

Comment: `print(geod)` yields `Geod('+a=6378137 +f=0.0033528106811822724')`, which throws an error in `g = pyproj.Geod(ellps=geod)`: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Geod'`

Comment: `geod` is the `pyproj.Geod` object. No need to pass it in.